# Program/Service to automatically backup Dropbox

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, backup, cloud-storage

I'm looking for a program,  or (preferably) a Web service to automatically archive and backup my entire Dropbox every once in a while. If it were a Web service,  it would be nice if it could store the archived file (.7z, .zip, .gz, etc) in another cloud service,  like Google Drive,  One Drive,  or on its own servers, and gives me access to the download(s).

**Things I need it to have/be:**

- Store files in a single archived file      such as a .zip
- Gratis
- Works with Windows and/or GNU/Linux
- Ability to set how often it backs up (or a decent set time,  such as every week)
- obviously,  it needs to be secure/trustworthy,  since it'll be handling important files

**Things that would I would prefer it to have,  but not required:**

- Compress the files as much as possible to save space
- Runs as a Web service so I don't have to download anything,  or even have my computer on for it to work
- Ability to have multiple backups at once
- Backups to another cloud service
- Password protected archives

Currently,  I just use 7zip to create archives manually every once in a while,  but this gets annoying and I often forget to do a backup.

By the way,  I have all my files synced to my hard drives on both my Windows,  and Linux computer using the official Dropbox program,  so it doesn't necessarily need to be designed just for Dropbox,  where I have to sign in. A general backup program would work,  as long as it does what I need.

Comment: I would suggest looking into using either the windows scheduler or cron to do the backup for you. These can be setup so that they will run at given intervals (and/or on the next start up of your computer ). No particular software needed just some configuration. This configuration, if to hard for you, is a good fit for the Super User stack exchange site...

Comment: I wonder why you would want to backup your DropBox files? They are already backed up on the DB server. Are you converged that that will go down? Then you still have local copies. Concerned that you will lose those? Then back them up. Want them backed up automatically in the cloud? Then backup your local DB data to a service like https://spideroak.com/